# Coin Tossing program in C/ Else vs Else if received values from rand()

Tags: c

I wrote this simple program to simulate coin tossing. It seems to be working fine, however when "else" replaced with "else if" program does not produce expected results.

"Else" covers all possible scenarios when the first "IF" conditions are not met and program executes fine. 
When I try to use "else if ( flip() )" instead of "else", not all of the results are being displayed. I would expect from below, that whenever function - "flip()" does not return 0, it returns 1, therefore  "else if ( flip() )" condition becomes true, and "heads" count is increased. But what actually happens - "heads" count is reduced at least twofold(in comparison to using "else"), i.e "else if ( flip() )" does not catch all returned values, when flip()returns anything other than 0. 
I understand, there is no really need to use "else if" here, but would be very grateful if someone could explain though, why in this case "else if" does not produce same results. What am I missing? 
Many thanks.

```
int flip ( void);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int tails = 0, heads = 0;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){   // 100 tosses 

    if ( flip() == 0){
        tails++;  // increase tails count
        printf("Tails  ");
        }
    else{         // else if ( flip () ) - replacement for "else"
        heads++;  // increase heads count
        printf("Heads  ");
        }

    if ( i % 10 == 0){
        printf("\n"); 
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nTotal count is:\n%d for Heads\n%d for Tails\n", heads, tails);

    return 0;
}

int flip ( void )
{
    return  rand()%2;
}
```

Comment: If you call it again the value may be different.

Comment: Because when the `else` case flips the coin again, you now have a further 50/50 chance. It's not the same coin flip, but a new one. So the `heads` count will be approximately half what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the `if ( flip() == 0)` branch of the if statement and the `else if ( flip() )` branch will both execute `flip()` separately. This means that those edge cases where the program acts unexpectedly are caused by the two branches returning different numbers.

If you insist on adding the other branch however, or for anyone else who may come across this answer with the same problem, the simplest solution I can think of would be to:

### Store the Return Value into a Variable

Simply defining a variable at the beginning of the for loop to hold that iteration's `flip()` result and testing against that will suffice for what you are trying to accomplish.

Specifically speaking, I would declare the variable before the beginning of the loop (`int result;`) and re-define it at the beginning of each loop iteration so as to re call the function each time. (`result = flip();` before the if statement in question)

Another solution would be to:

### Use a Switch Statement

Switch statements are kind of like modified if/else statements except they test many different cases on one thing, for example

```
switch ( flip() ) // test against the result of flip()
{
        // if it happens to be zero
        case 0:
                tails++;
                printf("Tails ");
                break;
                // the break statement tells the program to stop this case
        // if it happens to be one
        case 1:
                heads++;
                printf("Heads ");
                break;
}
```

Although it may appear to be overcomplicated if you decide to forgo the variable route, I think that the utility switch statements can add to your programs make it well worth it. (especially if there are numerous if branches)

**TLDR:** the `flip()` is getting called twice, see under the headers for solutions and above for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if ( flip () )
```

calls `flip()` a second time. So, your tails will increase with a 50% chance, but your heads only with a 25% chance.

You could emulate it with a real coin: It heads come up, **don't** tally that, toss again, and only tally heads if it is heads **again**.